# Extract Boxed enum from a enum in rust

Tags: rust, enums

I am writing an interpreter for a Scheme-like language in Rust. I coded the AST as an enum:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Object {
    Integer(i64),
    Boolean(bool),
    Character(char),
    String(String),
    Symbol(String),
    Cons { car: Box<Object>, cdr: Box<Object> },
    Nil,
}

pub type ObjectBox = Box<Object>;
```

I wanted to add a `car(&self) -> ObjectBox` method to `Object`. I came up with:

```rust
impl Object {
    pub fn car(&self) -> Option<ObjectBox> {
        match self {
            Object::Cons { car, cdr: _ } => Some(ObjectBox::new(**car)),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}
```

On compiling I get this error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `**car` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/core/object.rs:94:65
   |
94 |             Object::Cons { car, cdr: _ } => Some(ObjectBox::new(**car)),
   |                                                                 ^^^^^ move occurs because `**car` has type `object::Object`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
```

I understand why the error is happening, but I am unable to come up with a way to fix it. Can this be done with my current `Object` implementation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot move out of a `&self`, so you have few options:

1. Consume `self`:

```rust
impl Object {
    pub fn car(self) -> Option<ObjectBox> {
        match self {
            Object::Cons { car, cdr: _ } => Some(ObjectBox::new(*car)),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e9e2932674e13a41b5300a9bca161f6e)

2. Return a reference:

```rust
pub type ObjectBox<'a> = Box<&'a Object>;

impl Object {
    pub fn car(&self) -> Option<ObjectBox> {
        match self {
            Object::Cons { car, cdr: _ } => Some(ObjectBox::new(car.as_ref())),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=539a29845b657d5c5c4dd1246fe94b33)

3. Clone what you need:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub enum Object {
    Integer(i64),
    Boolean(bool),
    Character(char),
    String(String),
    Symbol(String),
    Cons { car: Box<Object>, cdr: Box<Object> },
    Nil,
}

pub type ObjectBox = Box<Object>;

impl Object {
    pub fn car(&self) -> Option<ObjectBox> {
        match self {
            Object::Cons { car, cdr: _ } => Some(ObjectBox::new(*car.clone())),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f38b3de4a9c80d2650946df98e4a6c40)

3.1 As suggested by @KevinReid, you could change `Box` to `Rc`, so you can get a cheaply clonable pointer to the object:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub enum Object {
    Integer(i64),
    Boolean(bool),
    Character(char),
    String(String),
    Symbol(String),
    Cons { car: ObjectBox, cdr: ObjectBox },
    Nil,
}

pub type ObjectBox = Rc<Object>;

impl Object {
    pub fn car(&self) -> Option<ObjectBox> {
        match self {
            Object::Cons { car, cdr: _ } => Some(car.clone()),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=29e5fefd70f1377090f39e0aa9f3750b)

Comment: There is also option 3 but using `Rc`/`Arc` instead of `Box`, to share structure instead of deep cloning. That might be desirable for supporting a Lisp style of programming.

Comment: @KevinReid, atually yes, `Rc` would solve do it here too.